# Is this set of functions linearly dependent or independent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

The given functions are solutions to a differential equation

\begin{equation*} y_1(x)=\cos(2x),y_2(x)=1,\;y_3(x)=\cos(x) \end{equation*}

I need help determining if the set of functions are linearly dependent or independent.

Taking the Wronskian:

\begin{equation*}
W(y_1, y_2, y_3) = \begin{vmatrix}
    \cos(2x) & 1 & \cos(x) \\
    -2\sin(2x) & 0 & -\sin(x) \\
    -4\cos(2x) & 0 & -\cos(x)
\end{vmatrix} 
= -4\sin^3(x)
\end{equation*}

I am not sure if this result tells us linear dependence or independence, as some definitions I found online say that if the wronskian is nonzero for some point x, then the set of functions are linearly independent. And some sources say that the wronskian must be nonzero for every x in order for the set of functions to be linearly independent. I am probably missing something here. Any help is appreciated.

[Claim 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ6IL.png)

Comment: Can you please share your sources for each of your claims? Your functions are LI, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#The_Wronskian_and_linear_independence

Comment: @PNDas I have updated my post with one of the claims, which is from this [textbook](https://www.amazon.com/Course-Differential-Equations-Modeling-Applications/dp/1111827052)

Comment: @user5587, Ricky has already answered it but please see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity too.

Answer (score 0):

A sufficient but not necessary condition for a set of differentiable functions to be linearly independent on an interval is that [their Wronskian does not **vanish identically**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian). Their dependence depends not only on the functions themselves but also on the interval. In your example, these functions are independent if the interval is not degenerate.

Comment: Does this contradict your statement?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ6IL.png

For this problem the interval is non-degenerate

Comment: @user5587 
Wronskian vanishing identically alone does not imply linear dependence, you need some extra conditions. In your case, the functions being solutions of a homogeneous linear differential equation will make sure they are linearly dependent.